# Generating a random double number with one number decimal point

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, random, double

I have to generate a number between **-4.0** and **4.0** including all numbers like *3.4* etc. I have managed to create a *random integer* but got stuck when creating `double` - it just returns an `integer`.

Comment: Would you mind posting the code that you have: much easier to provide a solution around framework you already have.

Comment: I already found the solution to the problem but if you're interested than I can post the code I used.

Comment: When asking a question about code, please _always post code_ of what you've already tried. If you haven't tried anything, then that is what you should do **first**. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.NET Random` class provides a method `NextDouble()` which can be used in this case. But a workaround for your case would be much easier and faster to implement. Such as:

```
Dim r As Random = New Random()
Dim d As Double = r.Next(-4, 4) + (r.Next(0, 9) / 10) 'First random next call in desired range, and second is to add the decimal point

Console.WriteLine("Generated Number: {0}", d)
```

Comment: Another more clear way would be `Dim d as Double = r.NextDouble() * 8 - 4`. NextDouble() returns a number between 0 and 1 (like the legacy Rnd() function). Multiplied by 8 gives a range between 0 and 8, minus 4 for the lower boundary. Oh and for the "one decimal point" just use `Math.Round(d, 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

One work around can be that you get a *random* `int` between -40 and 40, then divide the result by 10.

Comment: This was the easiest option. Thanks a lot.